# PyQt4 QFileSystemModel duplicated index

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I have a problem with QFileSystemModel.index

When I select files or folders from treeview with one click of the mouse, the code prints the item selected twice.

This is the part of the code where I am having the problem :

```
import sys
import os
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant',2)
.....
.....
self.pathRoot = QtCore.QDir.rootPath()
self.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(self)
self.model.setRootPath(self.pathRoot)

self.fsindex = self.model.setRootPath(self.model.myComputer())
self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.fsindex)
self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)
self.treeView.setColumnHidden(3, True)
self.treeView.setColumnHidden(2, True)
self.treeView.setColumnWidth(0, 320)
self.treeView.setColumnWidth(1, 30)
self.treeView.resizeColumnToContents(True)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
    indexItem = self.model.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())
    filePath = self.model.filePath(indexItem)
    print filePath
```

Comment: Your code is correct and I can not reproduce your problem.

Comment: thanks ; the problem still happen ; print filePath give me the same name twice everytime ; and dupicated items in the combobox

Comment: Which combobox?

Comment: to not have that problem because you do not work with the double click.

Comment: i check again and the problem from qt designer ; if i put the qtreeview inside widget or QVBoxlayout i got this problem !

Comment: and this is not the problem ; something wrong in qt designer !

Comment: This happens because of the [Connecting Slots By Name](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name) feature. The pyuic tool can automatically connect signals to slots based on a simple naming convention. To fix your code, you can either use a different name for the slot, or remove the line in your code that connects the signal.

Comment: problem solved but i don't know why it happened ; i rename treeView to treeview

Comment: thank you all ; the problem fixed ; ekhumoro is right if he mean to rename treeView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the following line in the file generated when compiling Qt Designer.

```
QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SOME_OBJECT)
```

According to the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName):

> **QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName (QObject o)**
>
> Searches recursively for all child objects of the given object, and
>   connects matching signals from them to slots of object that follow the
>   following form:
>
> `void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);` Let's
>   assume our object has a child object of type QPushButton with the
>   object name button1. The slot to catch the button's clicked() signal
>   would be:
>
> void on_button1_clicked();

that is to say that it connects the slots and the signals that contain that syntax, and in your case that happens so you have 2 options:

- Delete the connection you make.
- Or rename your slot.

Comment: thank you ; and sorry i can't vote because i am new member

Comment: @seghier You can not vote but you can mark a response as correct for it must mark the arrow that is to the left side of my answer, to have more information check the following: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @eyllanesc i have the same problem, the more times i click the TreeView the more times it prints the filepath instead of once...pls how can i rename my slot or what better method can i use...

Comment: @X-Black... Without a code, I can not tell you anything.

Comment: '    def on_clicked(self, index):
        #self.path = self.fileSystemModel.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        self.path = self.fileSystemModel.filePath(index)
        #print(self.path)
        #self.temp_delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_file)
        #self.duplicate_delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_file)
        #self.unused_delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_file)

        self.temp_zip_button.clicked.connect(self.zip_file)




    def zip_file(self,):
        print(self.path)
        
'

Comment: @eyllanesc the print() in the on_clicked() prints once at time but the print in the zip_file() prints repeatedly...

Comment: The problem is another one, you are connecting the button with the zip_file slot every time, do not make the connection in the on_clicked, but below the creation of the button:

`self.temp_zip_button = QPushButton('Zip file')`
`self.temp_zip_button.clicked.connect (self.zip_file)`

The connection does not verify if the connection with any slot was made previously.

Comment: @eyllanesc I actually did it that way before it didn't work that's why i tried manipulating the code...i did it the normal way again..surprisingly it worked..thanks again